# Incremental approach in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a source table like below
Source table :
Day1: table

Id value start_date
100 v1   2017-01-01
101 v2   2017-02-01

Day1 data should be loaded like below
Target table 
Id value start_date end_date
100 v1   2017-01-01 2099-12-31
101 v2   2017-02-01 2099-12-31

In day2, new record should be inserted based on the condition source.value<>target.value

New record end_date should be 2099-12-31 and previous row end_date should updated with current date like below
Target table

Id value start_date end_date
100 v1   2017-01-01 2017-09-19
100 v2.  2017-01-01 2099-12-31
101 v2   2017-02-01  2017-09-19
101 V3   2017-02-01 2099-12-31

Please note source table will be refreshed every day.

Please help me to get the out put of target table mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider below points before finalizing and approach, like...

1. Number of records are very huge then, use Hbase to store the data since updates are allowed and build hive external table referring to the same I doubt if this will affect queries using the joins for hive-hbase table with large ORC hive tables
   For less number of records use incremental load suggested by HDP, https://hortonworks.com/blog/four-step-strategy-incremental-updates-hive/
2. How to handle the issue if something goes wrong? : The 4th step in [HDP approach](https://hortonworks.com/blog/four-step-strategy-incremental-updates-hive/) deletes base table and recreate with new data. Consider you have noticed an issue with data after couple of days, how do you get deleted base_table? if you have answer then go for [HDP approach](https://hortonworks.com/blog/four-step-strategy-incremental-updates-hive/).
3. Approach 3: You are choosing point 1 because Hbase supports updates but hive does not support updates (I guess this is your understanding). Yes your understand was correct with old hive version. But Update is available in starting Hive 0.14

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Update